# Replace AJAX after successful load and error handling

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I have this simple AJAX load method to load an URL:

```
<div id="load">
<h1 id="status">Loading...</h1>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
   var url = "http://www.example.com/get.php?id=12345";          
            $('#load').replaceWith($('<div>').load(url));
});
});
</script>
```

At the moment I dont ever see the `Loading...` whilst the AJAX is loading, however shouldnt my method only replace it after it's loaded the new content. On a side note, if the AJAX load failed, how would I go about replacing that status class with `Failed`

Comment: perhaps the replaceWith is executing immediately

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

if you load the page into a `$('<div>')` - then use the .load callback to complete the replacement of `status` - like so

```
<div id="load">
<h1 id="status">Loading...</h1>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
    var url = "http://www.example.com/get.php?id=12345";          
    $('<div>').load(url, function() {
      $('status').replaceWith(this);
    });
  });
</script>
```